# How to check if user is logged in or anonymous in Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

When the root controller ("/") is called, I want to check if the user has authenticated or not. If he is not authenticated I want to display home page while if he is I want to display dashboard like so:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String homePage() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    if(authentication == null) return "home";

    return "dashboard";
}
```

But when I run the program, it tries to display dashboard, which means that **clearly the if() condition returned false**. But I know that I definitely did not log in. Why does this not work.

Also, I know I could override the configure(HttpSecurity http) method in the  WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter like so:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").authenticated();
```

**But this would redirect me to the /login page**, which is ok for any other request but not ("/") where I want to be redirected to "home" page if no session exists.

This is the value of authentication after a Sysout: `org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@52132976: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to disable anonymous authentication, see [`HttpSecurity#anonymous`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.12.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#anonymous--):

> The following demonstrates how to represent anonymous users as null. Note that this can cause `NullPointerException` in code that assumes anonymous authentication is enabled.
>
> ```java
> @Configuration
> @EnableWebSecurity
> public class AnononymousSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
>
>     @Override
>     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>         http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER").and().formLogin()
>                             .and()
>                             // sample anonymous customization
>                             .anonymous().disabled();
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
>               auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
>     }
> }
> ```

or you could check for class `AnonymousAuthenticationToken`. Your modified code:

```java
@GetMapping("/")
public String homePage() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    if (authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) return "home";

    return "dashboard";
}
```

Comment: There is no method called "disabled()" after .anonymous() Rather a method called "disable()" is there. Do you mean to refer to that method?

Comment: I tried the first method(with .disable()) but it caused problems. But the second method worked perfectly for me.

Comment: @YeetCoder You are right, it is an error in Spring Security's API Doc. I guess it should be `disable`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the fastest way to do so (worked with me in my app) is the following:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public Boolean isLoggedIn(Principal principal) {

    if(principal == null) return "home";

    return "dashboard";
}
```

It should be noted that in my app I already configured all the security stuff. This means that if my solution won't work with you (hope not), know that you have to configure all the security stuff too (check Spring Security courses).

Answer (score 0):

With the current version of spring security, you could add a role of anonymous authenticated user in the security configuration class; then restrict that role for accessing paths requiring not anonymous.